# Nodejs crashing silently when trying to aceess file system with "fs"

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I'm currently working on an Nodejs API server with Express. and on a specific path i had this,

```
const fs = require("fs/promises");
fs.mkdir(folderPath, {recursive: true})).then(console.log).catch(consolle.log);
```

"folderPath" is the full path of the folder that i want to create. now when the execution reaches this line the NodeJs server crashes silently without any trace, nothing in the log files, nothing in the try/catch block for the code, nothing in the Express error handler. The request to that specific route will get a 503 error, which is not from express, and i think this error originates from the server it'self after NodeJS crashes.

To make sure that the error is not caused by the parameters passed to fs.mkdir i specifically put the above lines of code into the entry file (index.js) where express app is started, and replaced "folderPath" with an actual path that i'm sure exists.

```
const fs = require("fs/promises");
fs.mkdir("/home/abcd/efg", {recursive: true})).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

And the NodeJS server crashes as soon as i start it, with out any trace just like i mentioned above.

The next thing i tried is running a "test.js" file with the above lines of code from the terminal as, test.js only contains those two lines of code.

```
node test.js
```

test.js is located within the same folder as index.js, and surprisingly it works. the folder get's created without no error, which leaves me confused. Why would it fail when running from index.js, but works fine when running from test.js.

what am i doing wrong here that's causing the crashes, is there a permission thing that i'm not aware of, or is it something else.

here is some detail of the server:
[image: Server Information]

I'm using Node 14.7.0. One other thing is that when the sever crash occurs large size files named "core####" (eg core3424) are created in the api root folder, where index.js is. and also Number of processes and Memory usage Max out.

Comment: Here is the server info, https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BCjL.png

Comment: Do you notice that in `catch(consolle.log);` `consolle` is misspelled.  That would cause it to throw when the code tries to reference `consolle.log`.

Comment: Check the `stderr.log` file in your hosting file manager.

Comment: Also mention worthy is that you don't pass anything into the console.log and no function inside the then and catch block.

Comment: stderr.log is empty, also the passenger log file is empty. Passing console.log to then and catch will simply log the data.